# Latest opera broken speed dial and rendering bugs

Tags: opera

Running `opera 32.0.1948.25 x86_64` (latest release) on Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS.

Anybody else getting bugs like these:

[image]

All my extensions are disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue (on the exact same versions of Opera and Ubuntu).
You can fix this problem by following these steps:
- Go to "Edit" -> "Preferences" -> "Browser".
- Scroll down to "Advanced settings" and check "Show advanced settings".
- A "System" section will show up. Uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available".
- Restart Opera.